# What is the minimum secure length for gpg -c file.txt?

Tags: password, encryption, security

I want to use gpg -c with a user generated password that I can easily remember. Is 16 characters enough? for example would a password similar to "I own 32 houses." be bruteforcable?

Comment: Not an Ubuntu-related question. Plenty of ressources on that on the Internet, but no, that passphrase is not secure. Everything is brute-forcable, it's just a matter of how long it takes. I'd recommend coming up with a random series of letters and numbers that you can still memorize - it's not that hard if you use it every day. Avoid anything you can find in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

How you generate your passwords is important. You've chosen three words and a small number for your example, and I'm guessing the three words were chosen from a list of hundreds of words, maybe two thousand. (At least I seem to have '2000' in mind as the average person's daily vocabulary.)

Choosing a word at random from 2000 gives you around 11 bits of entropy. Three such words would be 33 bits. Your number 32 is five bits long, so lets pretend it contributes the full five bits. That's 38 bits of entropy, under some very generous assumptions. Modern GPUs can approach this size problem in a second or so, though I don't know if GPG's `-c` option is covered by existing tooling or not. Anyway, I think your example passphrase is not useful for anything important.

Here's a tool I got from a friend, Aaron Toponce. It's possible I've extended it a bit, so any bugs remaining should be considered mine:

```bsh
gen-pass(){
        echo "Generating passwords with 80-bits of entropy"
        [[ $(echo "$1" | grep -E '[0-9]+') ]] && NUM="$1" || NUM=1
        for I in $(seq 1 "$NUM"); do
                strings /dev/urandom | grep -o '[a-hjkmnp-z2-9-]' | head -n 16 | tr -d '\n'
                echo # blank string
        done | column
}
```

You use it like this:

```
$ gen-pass 
Generating passwords with 80-bits of entropy
fx6kycwsktr8v5gq
$ gen-pass 10
Generating passwords with 80-bits of entropy
re784jv4ha9-sxmn    ju68qfwwtc88p4cu    9s-m5fv7rg34fgnt    3vazc9hqs2ypk8wr    ncceast25bv972h9
gemaq873n7funqnr    jj6sq5zwkbmnh9jt    s2whnmzv435gdvd6    sctxjk97tb4bar6q    3qvtkg9-d32cd8ch
$
```

The `grep -o` is complicated to skip 'difficult' characters like `i1l o0`. Because there are 32 characters selected, each one provides five bits of security: sixteen characters time five bites each gives a total of 80 bits of security. This is significantly lower than usual AES keys, with 128 bits of security, but it is an approachable size for people. You can amend the '16' in the example to reach whatever security margin you need. (It'd be nice to update the output, as well, to make sure you know what you're getting when you use it.)

Using this, or another tool like it, that generates passwords using an algorithm designed to output a password with specified properties, is much safer than trying to be random yourself.